# Rotate binary tree without grandchildren

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Trying to understand binary tree rotation. All resources on the internet explain it using unbalanced trees (such as having different branch heights). 
But I want to understand how to rotate this kind of tree? Or maybe is it not legal at all?:

```
  3
 / \
1   5
```

And how it would look in case for example left rotation?:

```
    5
   /
  3
 /
1
```

PS: I don't care about balance I just want to know is it appropriate to rotate this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if it's appropriate, you only have to check that every left subtree contains smaller elements than the root and every right subtree contains greater ones. (If you've got duplicates in the tree, equality is allowed too.)

If that is true, you've got a valid binary search tree. That's all that matters.

(And yes, the example you give is a left rotation, as the right child of the root is pulled up to be the root, with everything else staying the same because the pivot element (5) didn't have a child.)

Answer (score 1):

Tree rotation is used for changing the structure of a BT. So, of course, you can rotate your tree as you want (by specifying the rotation condition) but mostly it's used for rebalancing BSTs so that to get a `O(log(N))` performance during `search/insertion/removal`.